# How to setup module's own database

Tags: php, oop, module, yii2

I want to setup module's database independent from base project and configure it from config/web.php like the following:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        ///...
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=klabs',
            'username' => 'postgres',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is it available to make so? And how to do it, if yes?

Answer (score -1):

First, you need config other database components like that:

```
...
    'components' => [
        'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1name',
            'username' => 'db1username',
            'password' => 'db1password',
        ],
        'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port:5432dbname=db2name',
            'username' => 'db2username',
            'password' => 'db2password',
        ],
    ],
...
```

And choose db component you defined before in your module config:

```
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'other\to\UserModule',
            'layout' => 'main',
            'db' => 'db2', // or db1
            ...
        ],
    ],
```

Hope it helpful.

Goodluck and have fun!